# How do I efficiently remove bottom half elements of a stack in Java?

Tags: java, arrays, data-structures, stack

How can I devise an efficient method in Java to remove bottom half elements in a stack?  For instance:
My stack is : (1,2,3,4,5,6). The output is 4,5,6. Another example where the input is ( 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11). The output will be from 6 to 11.

Comment: You need to show your stack implementation first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this:

```
int center = stack1.size() / 2;
//Remove the half
int counter = 0;
for(int i=0; counter<center;counter++) {
    stack1.remove(i);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have count of elements in stack, you can just pop off first half and then print next half (push it to another stack if you dont want to lose your elements)

If you dont have count of elements in stack, you need to create another stack(say stack2), pop elements from stack1 and push to stack2 and then keep counts of elements.

Once you have got the count, pop elements from stack2 and push in stack1 and only print the first half elements being popped off from stack2.

Comment: First paragraph is what I am looking for ! Thanks!

Comment: @dryre you got 2 answers posted. You can mark 1 of them as solution which one you think is better.